# if reg key doesnt exist - Unhandled exception

Tags: vb.net

I have code to check if the registry does not exist then create it.

Strange thing is, this works perfectly on my windows 7 machine.. If i run it on my windows 10 tablet, it does not work?

I get an Unhandled Exception error:

Access to the registry key: 'HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\EdgeUI' is denied.

My code:

```
Dim TabletEdgeSwipe As Object = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey("SOFTWARE\\Policies\\Microsoft\\Windows\\EdgeUI", True)
If TabletEdgeSwipe Is Nothing Then
    Registry.LocalMachine.CreateSubKey("SOFTWARE\\Policies\\Microsoft\\Windows\\EdgeUI").SetValue("AllowEdgeSwipe", "0", RegistryValueKind.DWord)
End If
```

Comment: Did you try to launch your app in admin?

Comment: That solves the issue! Wow. How come that happens on the windows 10 machine and not the win 7?

Comment: just depends if the user deactived or reduced the UAC level

Comment: Well i have UAC disabled on both win 7 and win 10.

Comment: Will just have the app always run as admin, its a app which needs to run on startup and take up the whole screen. So il just set it in properties to always start with admin rights. Thanks for this! Been doing try, catch methods and all sorts to try fix this!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### A requestedExecutionLevel Problem

This is simply that the application doesn't have the right to access this part of the registry.

You can change the **app.manifest**

If you can't see the app.manifest

1. Double Click (**MyProject**)
2. Click (**View Windows Settings**)

**Change this line :**

```
<requestedExecutionLevel level="asInvoker" uiAccess="false" />
```

**To :**

```
<requestedExecutionLevel level="requireAdministrator" uiAccess="false" />
```

This will force the app to be launched or asked to be launched as **Administrator**

---

### Note:

You could also use:

```
level="highestAvailable"
```

The [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb756929.aspx) states:

> The application runs with the highest privileges the current user can
>   obtain.

This means that if the user has **Admin privileges** instead of running it with current security settings it will launch it was maximum available as **Admin** in our case.

Comment: haha literally just changed that! Searched it up seconds after my last comment. - Thanks again for the help ;)

Comment: @irishwill200 No problems make sure marked as answered to finish the question.

Comment: Maybe add a note about level: highestAvailable <-- Might be beneficial to some. Will do once im allowed.

Comment: Strange thing, with the above done. I still get the denied error! If i run manually with admin rights, it works again.

Comment: Make sure you use `requireAdministrator` also make sure you release your project in correct debug or release folder. Furthermore make sure if your trying in debug mode that Visual Studio is launched as admin.

Comment: Another rebuild solved it. Very strange, but i guess VB always has strange bug encounters xD